# How to insert element before specific sublist?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have the following list, for which I want to insert 'x' before each element that have 't' in first element of each sublist.

```
z = [['a', 2], ['t',4], ['r',9], ['t',1], ['u',2], ['p',7], ['y',9], ['t',1], ['s',3], ['v',1]]
```

My expected output is:

```
z = [['a' 2], x, ['t',4], ['r',9], x, ['t',1], ['u',2], ['p',7], ['y',9], x, ['t',1], ['s',3], ['v',1]]
```

My current code almost work, but I don't know why before the third sublist that has 't' is not inserting 'x' and instead is inserting two 'x' before the second sublist that has 't'.

```
for sl in reversed(z):
    if sl[0] == 't':
        print(z.index(sl))  
        z.insert(z.index(sl),'x')

>>> print(z)

[['a', 2], 'x', ['t', 4], ['r', 9], 'x', 'x', ['t', 1], ['u', 2], ['p', 7], ['y', 9], ['t', 1], ['s', 3], ['v', 1]]
```

Why I'm doing wrong? how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mutating the list while iterating over it, and indices of the original list will change once you start inserting items, resulting in the index that implements the iterator of the `for` loop getting shifted.

Instead, you can build a new list with a list comprehension that outputs an additional `x` before the the current sublist if the first item of the sublist is `t`:

```
z = [i for c, n in z for i in (*('x' if c == 't' else ()), [c, n])]
```

`z` becomes:

```
[['a', 2], 'x', ['t', 4], ['r', 9], 'x', ['t', 1], ['u', 2], ['p', 7], ['y', 9], 'x', ['t', 1], ['s', 3], ['v', 1]]
```

Comment: it works excellent. Thanks so much. May you please if have chance to explain how this solution works? for example what is `i for c` and `n in z for i`
and the aterisc in this part what is the purpose `(*(..)`